# NestedScrollView scrolls on top when content changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `fragment_layout.xml` with two buttons (`filter_1_btn`, `filter_2_btn`) that perform filtering to the items of a `RecyclerView`. The problem is that when I scroll a bit (because the `TextView` above the buttons contains multiple lines of text) and then apply the filtering, then the `NestedScrollView` scrolls on top of the screen. Is there a way to stay at the same scrolled height after the filtering?

fragment_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="Very long random text..." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter_1_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Filter 1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter_2_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Filter 2"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: can you post the code of filtering, how are you setting data after filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the recyclerView's container is set to wrap_content , so when the height get smaller than the NestedScrollView, it gets scrolled to top.

you can fix it by providing a height larger than NestedScrollView :

So add minHeight :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="Very long random text..." />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter_1_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Filter 1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter_2_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Filter 2" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="1000dp">
           <!-- Add min height to support scrolling-->
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```